# Automatically dismiss underling modal view

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, stacked

I'm sharing this as it took me A while to figure out. This is if you need to get rid of a double stack of modal views IF it is pressent.

```
if(self.parentViewController.parentViewController)
        [self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I have a view that sometimes gets called from a modal view. In that case I would need to get rid of both views at the same time. While dealing with the situation where it was the only modal view. This worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of xCode 4.2 this is no longer working, The new way to deal with this situation is:

```
if(self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController)
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

As pointed out by @Hollance in a relevant thread of mine:

[iOS 5 SDK treating UIViews differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779195/ios-5-sdk-treating-uiviews-differently)

> "There is a new property in iOS 5 named presentingViewController. The meaning of parentViewController got changed a bit with the new container view controller API, so it may not always be set when you think it is. That's what presentingViewController is now for."