# iOS 5 SDK treating UIViews differently

Tags: iphone, uiview, modal-dialog, ios5, dismiss

My app which use to work perfectly being compiled in xCode 4.0.2 no longer works correcly compiled in xCode 4.2 with the new SDK.

My modal views are working very different, some states not being detected, or other dismissals not working. For example this use to work to dismiss 2 stacked modal views:

```
if(self.parentViewController.parentViewController)
        [self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
else
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now this just dismisses the first view...

I've been looking for documentation on these changes but have found none. Primary app delegate seems to be working differently too.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solved: This would be the new way to present that particular piece of code:

`if(self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController)
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    else
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController, if you have two views behind it else only self.presentingViewController will suffice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a new property in iOS 5 named `presentingViewController`. The meaning of `parentViewController` got changed a bit with the new container view controller API, so it may not always be set when you think it is. That's what `presentingViewController` is now for.

Comment: Thank you for the quick post Hollance, I'll be checking this out next week and check this off as answered if this works out.

Comment: Would it be right to say that the new code will not work on devices pre iOS 5?

Comment: @topace The presentingViewController property was introduced with iOS 5, so it won't work on earlier iOS versions.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)])
    [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // for IOS 5+
} else {
    [self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // for pre IOS 5
}
```

Comment: Better to do: `if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)]) { ... }` than using an exception.